# Is it possible to use the second partition while Live USB is in use

Tags: linux, usb, partitioning, usb-flash-drive, liveusb

Is it possible to use the second partition (storage) of a USB flash drive while the first partition containing a live OS (to be specific Linux Mint) is running?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is often done to create [persistence](https://www.debugpoint.com/2019/10/how-to-create-persistent-usb-ubuntu-linux-mint/) (i.e., the USB flash drive will retain changes). [Rufus](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/08/rufus-creating-persistent-storage-live.html) make it easy to create a persistent boot USB.